# Partial parsing with flex/antlr

Tags: parsing, antlr, pascal, flex-lexer

I encountered a problem while doing my student research project. I'm an electrical engineering student, but my project has somewhat to do with theoretical computer science: I need to parse a lot of pascal sourcecode-files for typedefinitions and constants and visualize all occurrences. The typedefinitions are spread recursively over various files, i.e. there is type a = byte in file x, in file y, there is a record (struct) b, that contains type a and then there is even a type c in file z that is an array of type b.
My idea so far was to learn about compiler construction, since the compiler has to resolve all typedefinitions and break them down to the elemental types.

So, I've read about compiler construction in two books (one of which is even written by the pascal inventor), but I'm lacking so many basics of theoretical computer science that it took me one week alone to work my way halfway through. What I've learned so far is that for achieving my goal, lexer and parser should be sufficient. Since this software is only a really smart part of the whole project, I can't spend so much time with it, so I started experimenting with flex and later with antlr.

My hope was, that parsing for typedefinitions only was such an easy task, that I could manage to do it with only using a scanner and let it do some parser's work: The pascal-files consist of 5 main-parts, each one being optional: A header with comments, a const-section, a type-section, a var-section and (in least cases) a code-section. Each section has a start-identifier but no clear end-identifier. So I started searching for the start of the type- and const-section (TYPE, CONST), discarding everything else. In flex, this is fairly easy, because it allows "start conditions". They can be used as various states like "INITIAL", "TYPE-SECTION", "CONST-SECTION" and "COMMENT" with different rules for each state. I wanted to get back a string  from the scanner with following syntax "  = ". There was one thing that made this task difficult: Some type contain comments like in this example: `AuEingangsBool_t {PCMON} = MAX_AuEingangsFeld;`. The scanner can not extract such type-definition with a regular expression.

My next step was to do it properly with scanner AND parser, so I searched for a parsergenerator and found antlr. Since I write the tool in C# anyway, I decided to use its scannergenerator, too, so that I do not have to communicate between different programs. Now I encountered following Problem: AFAIK, antlr does not support "start conditions" as flex do. That means, I have to scan the whole file (okay, comments still get discarded) and get a lot of unneccessary (and wrong) tokens.  Because I don't use rules for the whole pascal grammar, the scanner would identify most keywords of the pascal syntax as user-identifiers and the parser would nag about all those series of tokens, that do not fit to type- and constant-defintions

Now, finally my question(s): Can anyone of you tell me, which approach leads anywhere for my project? Is there a possibility to scan only parts of the source-files with antlr? Or do I have to connect flex with antlr for that purpose? Can I tell antlr's parser to ignore every token that is not in  the const- or type-section? Are those tools too powerful for my task and should I write own routines instead?

Comment: You'dd be better off to find a compiler for Pascal, and simply modify to report the information you want.  Otherwise you essentially need to build a parser.

Comment: Modify `f2c`, it is probably the simplest Pascal compiler out there.

Comment: Du you mean the Fortran77 to C-converter? I'm not sure, how I can use that. Moreover, rewriting a compiler seems like a huuuge task and I don't have unlimited time (alone reading the code seems to be very time-consuming - keep in mind, that I don't have the theoretical background of compilers beside the ~50 pages I read about it). It was planned to finish that project within 4 weeks and I've already spent about 2 weeks reading and trying out several tools. So, I'd appreciate a solution which involves the rough approach that I've already taken (using generators of some kind).

Comment: @SK-logic:  f2c seems pretty counterintuitive; I too think it is about Fortran.  Why are you suggesting that it is related to Pascal?

Comment: @IraBaxter, oops, I meant `p2c` of course.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off to find a compiler for Pascal, and simply modify to report the information you want.  Presumably there is such a compiler for your Pascal, and often the source code for such compilers is available.

Otherwise you essentially need to build a parser.   Building lexer, and then hacking around with the resulting lexemes, is essentially building a bad parser by ad hoc methods.   ANTLR is a good way to go; you can define the lexemes (including means to pick up and ignore comments) pretty easily, especially for older dialects of Pascal.   You'll need good BNF rules for the type information that you want, and translate those rules to the parser generator.   What you can do to minimize work, is to cheat on rules for the parts of the language you don't care about.  For instance, you could write an accurate subgrammar for assignment statements.  Since you don't care about them, you can write a sloppy subgrammar that treats assignment statements as anything that begins with an identifier, is followed by arbitrary other tokens, and ends with semicolon.   This kind of a grammar is called an "island grammar"; it is only accurate where it needs to be accurate.

I don't know about the recursive bit.  Is there a reason you can't just process each file separately?  The answer may depend on what information you want to know about each type declaration, and if you go deep enough, you may need a symbol table as well as an island parser.  Parser generators offer you no help for this.

Comment: I had that compiler idea, too, but when I saw the huge amount of code, I let that one pass. When I talked about my problem with some colleagues, one gave me the hint to try "Codeworker". That's what I'll do today, so that by next week I can decide which approach I will follow for the realization. I already started writing the grammar with ANTLR but don't quite understand, how to implement such an island grammar. Is there a way to write a longer comment and use code in it or do I have to write myself an answer for that? Let's ignore the recursion part for now. I plan to do it in a second step.

Comment: Free Pascal has a separate package for parsing its own dialect. It is meant for the document tool (doxygen like), but can be customized. It is called fcl-passrc. It will require a bit of a Delphi or at least C++ background though. Coco/R is also an option as already said.

Comment: @BigTarzan: If you have a compiler, this is by far the easiest approach IMHO.  Yes, there's a lot of code there but you only have find the place where the information you want has been collected; for what you appear to want, I'd guess the symbol table has exactly the data you want. So the idea is to leave the compiler alone and simply *add* a bit of code that collects what you want as the compiler processes the program.

Comment: @BigTarzan: You'll face the dog-cant-choose-between-food-bowls-so-starves problem of too-many-parser-generators.   Most of them are adequate so your first trick if you decide to go this route is simply pick one.    To write the island grammar, find a Pascal grammar for the Pascal dialect you care about; and decide which rules you are going keep as-is, and which ones you are going to simplify (e.g., replacing the grammar rules for assignment with a much simpler version).

Comment: @BigTarzan:  You can't write a longer Stack Overflow comment.  You can edit your original question to add more detail, including blocks of sample code.  Usually you're better off to write a new question that links back this one as background (see the "share" link to get a URL) that says, "My basic problem in parsing Pascal is described in <url>.  I've chose to write an island grammar.  Here's the part of the island grammar that I have.  <code>  Here's my problem <essay>.   How do <fix issue>?".  That'll get you lots of advice.

Comment: If I had to choose right now, I would take the ANTLR-island-route. You made me feel confident, that this is one way that's most probably gonna work out. When you say "find a Pascal grammar" do you really mean by searching the internet? I intended to write it down by myself, since there are only a dozen of structures that apply to my task. The rest of the code is to be ignored (that is the meaning of the island grammar, right?). Or am I underestimating this job?

Comment: If you've chosen ANTLR, you can likely find an ANTLR-compatible grammar for Pascal at the ANTLR site to use as a starting place.  "rest of the code is to be ignored" is the purpose of "island grammar", achieved by oversimplifying (almost to the point of triviality) the part of the grammar that you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

First, there can be type and const blocks within other blocks (procedures, in later Delphi versions also classes).

Moreover, I'm not entirely sure that you can actually simply scan for a const token, and then start parsing. Const is also used for other purposes in most common (Borland) Pascal dialects. Some keywords can be reused in a different context, and if you don't parse the global blockstructure, and only look for const and type in specific places you will erroneously start parsing there.

A base problem of course is the comments. Scanners cut out comments as early as possible, and don't regard them further. You probably have to setup the scanner so that comments are attached to the adjacent tokens as field (associate with token before or save them up till a certain token follows).

As far antlr vs flex, no clue. The only parsergenerator I have some minor experience in parsing Pascal with is Coco/R (a parsergenerator popular by Wirthians), but in general I (and many pascalians) prefer handcoded.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think that I'd get any answers to that specific question - at least not within a week. :)  I let np++ look through the files and haven't found any case where more than one "TYPE" or "CONST" appears (the regarded files consist mainly of type-definitions), but thanks for that idea.  Oh, I think, you are mistaken. I don't need those comments. I just mentioned them because they were a pain in the a.. with the dirty flex-only solution.

Comment: @Marco:  Yes, you can write a handcoded recursive descent parser for classic Pascal.  Its not so easy for something like Delphi10, which is a huge extension to classic Pascal.  For a full parser for that, I think you're crazy not to use a parser generator.  (I've done dozens for grammars for big languages).

Comment: @BigTarzan:  I don't think comments are a PITA; they are just part of the landscape you have to handle. (So is whitespace and included files).   Yes, they are best handled in a lexer.   Like parser generators, there's lots of lexers, but usually for a chosen parser generator, there's a clear choice of lexer.  I strongly suggest you stick with that clear choice, and learn to love it; the lexer generators by making it easy to describe the atoms of the language really solve about half of your problem, allowing you concentrate on the grammar.

Comment: Ira Baxter: I've worked on said FPC documentation parser which accepts most of D2009 and several constructs after. The problem is the complexity of the dialect, not the parser technology. Moreover that parser is already done, and there are no working free grammars of Delphi afaik